# Tensor compact/matrix form.

Tags: matrices, mathematical-modeling, tensors, fluid-dynamics

I have got this tensor $S_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i})$

Anyway I solve it for my problem and get

$$ S_{ij} = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & b1 & 0 \\
b1 & 0 & b3 \\
0 & b3 & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$

The question is why when I put it back in compact form  and perform $ 2(S_{ij} S_{ij})$ the following is obtained?

$$
 2(S_{ij} S_{ij}) = b1^2 + b3^2
$$

I don't how to put it back in compact form.

Thanks for your help,
Fred

Answer (score 1):

In your notation

$$S_{ij}S_{ij}:=\sum_{i,j}S_{ij}S_{ij}=\sum_{i}\sum_j S_{ij}S_{ji}=\operatorname{tr}(S^2), $$

as $S$ is symmetric by construction. The diagonal of $S^2$ has elements $(b^2_1,b^2_1+b^2_3,b^2_3)$ then

$$\operatorname{tr}(S^2)= 2(b^2_1+b^2_3).$$

Comment: @Federico did it help?